# Profile image size issue

Tags: 2013, user-profile, image-display

When uploading an image of up to 300x300 for profiles into SharePoint 2013 - SP automatically creates thumbnails for the image for use around the site; org browser, people search etc.  However if the image is for example 300px tall and only 200px wide the thumbnail is cropped badly (peoples chins/tops of their heads are missing).

I realise theres not much I can do to change the way SP works but if you know of a tool that will batch resize images (adding white padding to the image) that would be extremely helpful as there are around 1000 images to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used a tool called imagemagick from www.imagemagick.org

First I created a simple white square 300x300 for the background image to be under the actual user image - I realise there are other ways of using imagemagick to achieve the same thing but this seemed the simplest approach for me.
The next step is to resize the images to a suitable size (i.e. 300px wide or 300px tall)

```
mogrify -path "c:\temp\Resized photos" -resize 300x300 "c:\temp\Resized photos"\*.*
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b /s "c:\temp\resize~1\*.*"') do call composite -gravity center %%a     "c:\temp\background.png" %%a
```

Once that was complete I was able to run my profile image import as normal and have the user images not cropped incorrectly.

Comment: lol you should of noted that you wanted to resize the image out of sharepoint before importing! I though it was for as you import it would do the cropping and resizing for you! Technically its not a sharepoint question ;)

Answer (score 5):

goto site settings, under look and feel select image renditions.

here you can fiddle around to choose what you want to show with an image when sharepoint renders the profile image.

its found here:

[image: rendition click here]

select the image (thumbnail) by hovering over and click on edit renditions

[image: edit image]

these are the sizes to change to your liking:

[image: image size types]

click on the selected size to edit (scale is available)

[image: change image prop]

now select your rendition that you want as default

[image: select default type]

unfortunatly, once the rendering has started it cant be saved. What i mean is when you upload an image to sharpeoint it saves three scales and those a saved and used... the origional image is not saved. so if it saved the images cropped than it will be using the cropped images. You would need to reupload the image otherwise!

full details can be found here:

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/image-renditions-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Thats fine for one or two profile images but I am talking about editing 1000+ images and respective thumbnails.